# Is it possible to add jquery code in browser url (not from code base, directly in url)? and make it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, browser

Is it possible to add jquery code in browser url (not from code base, directly in url)? and make it work.

I have a situation, where I can't add the jquery code in codebase, but I need to manipulate an HTML attribute. What I have is, I can modify the URL which is getting added from content and I can change that.

So, my question is is there any way I can change the URL from content and add manipulate the HTML ?

To avoid the conflict of attacks, can I encode and add it from URL content (Not sure).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No.  Can you imagine the mayhem that could result if you (or your users) could?

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. It will be considered as attacks... but here is it possible to do with some encoding from content side ? edited my question

Comment: Is requirement to run `js` from address bar of browser ?

Comment: Yes, that would help too...